# Setting Up Social Authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, facebook-authentication, asp.net-authentication

I'm setting up social login in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application without using Identity.

I simply want to authenticate the user through Facebook, Google and LinkedIn and receive their info. I handle storing user info myself.

Here's what I've done so far which is giving me the following error:

> No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: facebook

Here's the Startup.cs file changes:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            // Added these lines for cookie and Facebook authentication
            services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieAuthenticationScheme")
                .AddCookie(options => {
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden/";
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
                })
                .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
                {
                    facebookOptions.AppId = "1234567890";
                    facebookOptions.AppSecret = "1234567890";
                });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Added this line
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

I then have this action method where I send the user to determine the provider we're using for authenticaiton e.g. Facebook, Google, etc. This code came from my ASP.NET Core 1.1 app which is working fine.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "Login/Callback"
        };

        // Add returnUrl to properties -- if applicable
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            properties.Items.Add("returnUrl", returnUrl);

        // The ASP.NET Core 1.1 version of this line was
        // await HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync(provider, properties);
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(provider, properties);

        return;
    }
```

I'm getting the error message when I hit the `ChallangeAsync` line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Scheme names are case-sensitive. Can you try with Facebook instead of facebook?

Comment: Not sure what part of the code you're referring to. Could you clarify please? Thanks.

Comment: Just realized what you were talking about and you're exactly right!!!!! It has be `Facebook` not `facebook`

Comment: You could not have picked a better username for yourself :-) Your middle name should be `laser accuracy`. Thanks again!

Comment: lol, thanks for the kind word @Sam. I posted my comment as an answer, in case other people would be interested.

Comment: And I accepted it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: facebook

Scheme names are case-sensitive. Use `provider=Facebook` instead of `provider=facebook` and it should work.

Comment: I'm also trying to add `LinkedIn` authentication. What would be the scheme for that? I tried `LinkedIn` but again, I'm getting the `no handler is configured` error.

Comment: Feel free to open a separate question (please post the link here). The answer is not complicated, but I'm sure many people will face similar issues at some point when migrating to 2.0.

Comment: Good point! Here's the link to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777071/setting-up-linkedin-oauth-authentication-in-asp-net-core-2-0